# Keeping DataGridView column headers Height at a logical Height

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

A `DataGridView` column header may be set with code below, this quite set multiline header labels just fit and nice.

[column shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLZIw.png)

```
ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
```

But a single line column header shapes quite ugly, namely a narrow row. Trying below code together to increase height even does not work:

```
Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.Padding = new Padding(0, 5, 0, 5)
```

Is there way both use `AutoSize` and get nice height of column header in case of single line labels?

Comment: IMO, it's not clear what you're asking (what is *logical Height*?). Possibly, add images that explain what you have and what you'd like to achieve. Also post whatever code you have that tries to.

Comment: thanks, added picture, code tried is above, nothing more, respecting this subject...

Comment: Column header can auto-wrap text that doesn't fit within the width. You just need to set the Column's `Wrap` property to `true`. The, auto-size the Columns to all Cells except the Header, so, if the Header's text is too long, it will wrap.

Comment: let me ask question like this: `How To Change Height of A Column Header If AutoSize Option Forces It To Be A Definite Height Which You Do Not Like`, here Padding does not help at all...

Comment: You can set the height of the Column Headers to whatever value you want. Use the `ColumnHeadersHeight` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set `ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode` to `AutoSize` then it is not allowed to change `Column Heigt` on run time in accordance with `Header Labels Length`.

You must add this code on initialize:

```
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 5, 0, 5);
```

Change '5' as you wish to what padding volume you would like see...

Comment: both understanding and solving my problem is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
```

Comment: please look at my comment above, thanks...